# Не могу редактировать слой с текстом в Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На макете, открытом в Photoshop становлюсь на слой с текстом выбираю инструмент "ТЕКСТ", но слой не активируется, а создается новый слоя для ввода текста. А родной текст на макете невозможно отредактировать.

Comment: этот вопрос не связан с программированием, Вам, скорее, на другой сайт: https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: скорее-всего текст преобразован в растр или смарт объект, тогда его невозможно редактировать.

Answer (score 1):

Сам я с Photoshop редко работаю и с Вашей проблемой не сталкивался ещё на практике. Но когда изучал эту программу где-то читал, что после выбора слоя и инструмента "ТЕКСТ" нужно кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши на слое с текстом. В появившемся контекстном меню выбираем "Редактировать".
P.S. Завтра установлю Photoshop и проверю.

Answer (score 0):

Выделить текст и, не отпуская правой кнопки мыши, нажать на шифт.

Comment: Нажать на шифт , отпустить ЛКМ и выделение остается. Можно менять шрифт, размер и т.д.

Comment: Для уточнения ответа - редактируйте его, а не добавляйте комментарии )